# why echo `echo -e "abc\nabc"` gives me "abc abc"?

Tags: linux, shell, echo

A question about linux-shell.

When I type

`` echo `echo -e "abc\nabc"` ``,

I got `abc abc` not `abc\nabc`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at what the different layers do individually:

```
$ echo -e "abc\nabc"
abc
abc
```

because `echo -e` expands backslash escapes such as `\n`. (At least the one you  used does; the behaviour is not consistent across shells.)

Then, you `echo` that output, unquoted; this replaces any sequence of whitespace (including linebreaks) with a single blank character each ("word splitting").

```
$ str="abc
abc"
$ echo $str
abc abc
```

If you quote the string, whitespace is preserved (and shell special characters have no effect):

```
$ echo "$str"
abc
abc
```

You can achieve the same by quoting your command substitution:

```
$ echo "`echo -e \"abc\nabc\"`"
abc
abc
```

You have to escape the inner double quotes then, though. Which is one of the reasons why instead of backticks, these days it's recommended to use `$(...)` for command substitution:

```
$ echo "$(echo -e "abc\nabc")"
abc
abc
```

And if this isn't just a learning example, be aware that `echo "$(cmd)"` is usually an antipattern and should be replaced by just `cmd`.

---

#### References

- [This](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/echo+printf/) is a great overview of how `echo` (and `printf`) behaves in different shells
- The [POSIX spec](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) for `echo` with the recommendation to rather use `printf` instead